# The Elevator Pitch?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What should the Elevator Pitch be? Should we have an official one? Might be good to have one for community ads and the like.

Comment: Just brainstorming here: "Blender.SE is a Blender community(?) for experts, beginners and hobbyists, who are all ready to answer and ask questions you might(/will? to be a bit more aggressive) have about Blender."

Comment: A searchable community driven database of ranked questions and answers.

Comment: A free, community-driven Q&A site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

Comment: Do note that some of the Blender for games thing applies solely to BGE, rather than to game development using models created in Blender; there's a certain degree at which we stop caring; we don't necessarily care about how to apply animations in Unreal, but we do care about how to get a high-quality .obj export for later use in a program that we don't need to worry about here.

Answer (score 6):

Blender.SE helps you to understand Blender3d in depth, not only face value. It is an original site with a special texture and color. When posting make the object clear so you don't drive the community off the edge. If you don't make your point the site will eventually be rendered useless and be driven off the SE grid.

Remember there is always another perspective to shed more light on the matter. We hope to see you on the scene and have you blend in to the mesh of enthusiastic users. We hope the site will be animated and useful.

Try us out!

Comment: puns intended...

Comment: haha. I love this. :)